# Is ZXing able to decode older versions of Data Matrix barcodes?

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I was able to implement ZXing on my iOS mobile app written in Xamarin.forms, but the scanner could only read the new standard ECC200 Data Matrix barcodes.  The app fails to decode older versions such as ECC140.  Unfortunately, these older version Data Matrix barcodes are what is affixed on all our inventories.  Is there a function call that I could make or plugin that I could use with ZXing to allow for decoding of different versions of Data Matrix barcodes?

ZXing does a great job at reading most 1D and 2D barcodes.  However, there doesn't seem to be support for different types of QR Codes such as Micro QR Codes or for older versions of Data Matrix.

Again, could ZXing read different versions of Data Matrix barcodes? And how?

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing#supported-formats

Comment: Thanks @Jason.  From the list you provided, Data Matrix is supported and I am able to scan the current standard ECC200 Data Matrix.  However, according to this website, https://www.keyence.com/ss/products/auto_id/barcode_lecture/basic_2d/datamatrix/index.jsp, the older versions of Data Matrix barcodes are different and have less modules.  Hence, ZXing could only decode the new standard not the older versions.  Unfortunately our company inventory has only the older version Data Matrix barcodes.